# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'. It is not possible to run the project build inside the docker container

Tags: javascript, docker, vue.js, dockerfile, nginx-config

Faced with the problem of building a project based on Vue 3 inside a Docker container together with Nginx.

Dockerfile:

```
# Non-prod as builder
FROM node:18.13.0 as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
RUN npm ci
COPY . .
# Build the project
RUN npm run build

# Prod
FROM nginx:1.19 as production-stage
RUN mkdir /app
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /app
COPY ./.nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
EXPOSE 80
```

nginx.conf:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;
events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
  include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;
  log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                    '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
  sendfile        on;
  keepalive_timeout  65;
  server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    location / {
      root   /app;
      index  index.html;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
      root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
  }
}
```

Docker build an image for me, I launch the container with the following command:

```
docker run -it -p 8080:80 --rm --name vue-app-1 user/vue-app
```

After trying to access it inside the browser using `localhost:8080` - there is no static.

Errors in the browser console:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
>
> manifest.json:1 Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.

But when I try to build a project without Nginx, everything is fine. What is the problem?

Comment: *Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'* sounds like you get an xml file not a json file

Comment: @Jens So, why it goes like this?

Comment: I think a configuration issue

Comment: @Jens I also provided the nginx.conf file, could you please take a look at it, are there any critical points there that could affect this? First time using nginx for serving statics.

Comment: Are you sure that when you build your app, the `manifest.json` file is added / created in the `dist` directory?

Comment: @Phil Yes, checked right now. /usr/share/nginx/html is located in that path.

Comment: Can you directly open `http://localhost:8080/manifest.json` in your browser? Check the other requests being made in your dev-tools _Network_ panel. Do they look right?

Comment: @Phil Yes, it opened to me a correct .json file. No network issues.

Comment: I didn't ask if there were network issues. Can you see the request for `manifest.json`? Is the URL correct or is it using a sub-path or something?

Comment: @Phil Btw, after the opening `http://localhost:8080/manifest.json` - it opens a JSON file. And after access `http://localhost:8080` I received a 200 response inside Network section, and the path is completely different `http://localhost:8080/my-project/manifest.json` - is correct?